# JAVACL on dual core

Tags: java, opencl

I am using Java Cl on Dual core system. I found 2 platforms one is "AMD" and one is Intel, each platform has one device.

```
should it not return one platform and two devices ?
```

Comment: The "AMD" is your graphics card, the "Intel" is your CPU.

Comment: should it not return two devices for my CPU (dual core system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both AMD and Intel provide OpenCL implementations for some of their CPUs and GPUs.  In the case of AMD, their OpenCL implementation also supports Intel CPUs.  Therefore, after installing the AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing (APP) SDK, your program will, at the very least, identify an AMD platform with one device, i.e. the CPU in your computer.  Once you install the Intel OpenCL SDK, you will have a second OpenCL implementation running on your computer that detects your CPU.  Therefore, querying the available platforms will return two platforms, each with one device.  Both devices are the same thing - your computer's CPU.  The difference is in what OpenCL implementation gets used to access that CPU - i.e. the Intel version or the AMD version.

Regarding the number of cores, OpenCL sees the CPU as a single device but it allows you to query how many compute units (i.e. physical cores) are present on the device (i.e. CPU).

Answer (score 1):

No, The device is your CPUs which appears as one device even if you have multiple sockets.

You write your code to be run on as many cores as is available (without needing to know how many that is)

Some GPUS have thousands of cores and it is much easier to work with them collectively as one device.

e.g. The [Tesla K10](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla-servers.html) has 3072 cores and not only do you not want to be telling each core what to do, but you can't easily. GPUs are designed for every core to be doing the same thing.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But why JavaCL returns me two platforms. My understanding was I have dual core system with no GPU, JAVACL will return me one platform having two devices.

Comment: If you have have a headless computer (no display) you might still have a GPU on board.  If you have a display, VGA, DVI or HDMI port you must have a GPU even if it is int he chipset.

Comment: CLPlatform platforms[] = JavaCL.listPlatforms();
  for(CLPlatform platform : platforms)
  {
   CLDevice devices[] = platform.listGPUDevices(true);
   System.out.println("GPU Devices found :- "+devices.length);
  }   I use this code but found no device.Its means no GPU device found in my system

Comment: A GPU is a Graphical Processor Unit.  Without it you can't display anything.  Just the fact you can read this message tell me you have one even if the library can't find it.